# When did we first hear about Rizzo's bouncin' baby boy?

Tags: mash

When does Sergeant Rizzo (G.W. Bailey) pour out his entire family lineage?

He says that he has a "bouncin' baby boy" named Billy Buba. What episode is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was in S10E17, [Promotion Commotion](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0638392/) when Luther Rizzo [made it clear](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_M%2aA%2aS%2aH_characters#Luther_Rizzo) that he was an American "with an American wife and American son (Billy Bubba)".

Comment: Ah man that episode gets me every time! :)